# Android: how to parse this XML?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I get this kind of XML,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bats>
<symbols timestamp="2012-12-19 10:10:47" count="7984">
<symbol name="A"/>
<symbol name="AA"/>
<symbol name="AA-"/>
<symbol name="AAAA~"/>
<symbol name="AACC"/>
<symbol name="AADR"/>
```

etc...

I need to extract only the elements in name="*text*".

Please how do I do this?

Thank for your help!

Comment: This is not a well-formed XML.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html ?

Comment: I don't think there will be an XML parser that handles such kind of **XML**. So I think you need to parse that as raw text.

Comment: @Neevek it looks like... any suggestion on how could I that?

Comment: @Neevek, you're right, but it's not really hard to make it valid ;)

Comment: @pietmau, that won't be difficult, use a simple state machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text you want to  parse is inside an attribute, you can parse it with a SAX parser like this inside your `startElement` method:

```java
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        String key;
        if(qName.equals("symbol")) {
           key = atts.getValue("name");
         }
    }
```

Edit:
I tought this would be only a fraction of your XML... you can't parse invalid XML.
However you could grab that XML and do something like that(in order to make it valid):

```
parsedXml.append("\n</bats>");
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is the text after name=   so your workaround wouldn't succeedd

Comment: this is not a workaround. This is the correct way to parse an attribute... In this example you'll be storing the 'name' value into a string(key)...(change that to an ArrayList and it'll suit your needs)